# Connecting old & new MacBook Pros with USB

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

This might be a dumb question!

I'm waiting for my 14" MBP and I'm preparing to transfer many files from my old mid-2014 Retina MBP.  I'm planning to use target disk mode on my old computer and transfer manually.

Can I use a regular old USB to USB-C cable (such as this: https://amzn.to/3mv4Arw) or would I need a different cable/adapter to connect the two computers using target disk mode?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlb37e8ca7/12.0/mac/12.0 for details

Answer (score 1):

That cable should work fine as that is the method documented by Apple as a supported means to transfer data.  The link provided by @nohillside documents this, and I repeat it here in case of a deletion or edit and for sake of completeness: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlb37e8ca7/12.0/mac/12.0

For those with a similar concern on pre-M1 computers Apple documents the process here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/12.0/mac/12.0

USB should work fine for this, as should FireWire or Thunderbolt cables if that is what you have on hand.  I have done this process on Apple Intel hardware so I am quite certain this works.  I have not done this with the new Apple silicon hardware so if I am mistaken on this working with FireWire and Thunderbolt then I'd appreciate a correction/clarification.